# Notebook is very slow

Tags: performance-tuning

Recently I wrote an algorith in the notebook of mathematica and it worked fine. The next day I reopennedd the same file and realised that it went very very slow...it took more than 10 seconds to do a command such as **Global** ....The notebook is less than 3 Mbs....It is really painful to work in such an envirement right now....Do you have an idea what can I do? Thanks.

Please note that I am an amateur so the commands I write are really simple

Comment: Without more info to go on, did you try restarting your computer?

Comment: @ChrisK,unfortunatelly I did...

Comment: I'd use the process of elimination, deleting parts of (a copy of) your notebook to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: @ChrisK, actually this happens to all notebooks I have...I wonder if there is a folder with temporar files like the microsoft word has , so if I delete those the system will become faster...

Comment: You might try a clean restart of Mathematica.  https://support.wolfram.com/12464

Comment: Are there any dynamic/interactive outputs?

Comment: @Kuba,  yes there are!!

Comment: @dmtri they could interfere of be heavy anyway, you can use menu Cell > DeleteAllOutput and see if it helps